# Solved: MinGW gcc settings cannot be updated correctly

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I am using  x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 10-win32 20220113)  in WSL and I would like to create a .lib which can be used in MVSC in Windows.

When I use the printf function inside my lib file, it cannot be linked using MVSC.

After debugging, I found out that besides printf, the functions  `__imp___acrt_iob_func` and `__mingw_vfprintf` are defined, which are MinGW specific functions.

[Included Functions before setting `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6fwv.png)

According to documentation and `_mingw.h` the user should be able to deactivate MinGW specific extended features after setting  `__MINGW_FEATURES__` to `0` and they should not change directly `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` to 0.

But setting `__MINGW_FEATURES__` to `0` does not deactivate the MinGW specific functions. Even passing the flag `-std=c11` while compiling does not solve the problem. A solution is to pass the option while calling the compiler `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0`. Setting the value inside the lib itself does not work.

So the current solution is:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0  -c File.c -o File.obj 

x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar  rcs File.lib File.obj
```

[Included Functions after setting `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RlgR.png)

- Is that a bug or an intended behaviour?
- Where are the functions `__imp___acrt_iob_func` and `__mingw_vfprintf` defined?

Comment: There are different MinGW versions. Mine (from MSYS2) doesn't even have `__MINGW_FEATURES__`. But it does have `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`. Did you browse `_mingw.h` locally or somewhere on the net? Perhaps your local copy doesn't actually say the things you read online? It seems `__MINGW_FEATURES__` is specific to the old non-w64 MinGW, while most (sane?) people use w64.

Comment: `msvcrt.dll` (C standard library that your MinGW uses) has an old buggy implementation of `printf`, that's why MinGW ships its own. Not sure where exactly it's implemented though.

Comment: Good hint! I was checking the _mingw.h on my machine instead of WSL. Indeed it has another implementation.

Comment: So the solution would be to write #include __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0 or #include  __MSVCRT_VERSION__ <ValueBiggerThan0xE00> at the beginning of the c file or to pass them using -D in Terminal while calling the compiler.